# Finding Variance of Piecewise Function of Two Random Variables

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, variance

I have a piecewise function of two random variables:
$$h(X,Y) = \left\{
\begin{array}{ll}
                  kXY \qquad \text{if } X\geq a\\
                  kaY \qquad \text{ if } X < a\\
                \end{array}
              \right.$$
where $X$~$f_X(x)$, $Y$~$f_Y(y)$ are independent and $a,k$ are constants. I got the expectation of $h(X,Y)$:
$$E[h(X,Y)] = k\big(aF_x(a)+\int_a^\infty xf_X(x)dx\big)E[Y],$$
but I'm not sure how to calculate the variance of $h(X,Y)$. Could anyone help with $Var(h(X,Y))$? Many thanks!

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange! A quick [tour](https://math.stackexchange.com/tour) will enhance your experience. Here are helpful tips to [write a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/9960#9960) and [write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Hi Michael, thanks for the help! I followed your equation and got: $$E[h(X,Y)^2] = k^2\big(aF_X(a) + \int_a^\infty x^2 f_x(x)dx\big) \int_{-\infty}^\infty y^2 f_Y(y)dy.$$ Hope I didn't mess it up...

Comment: Two things: (i) This should be $E[h(X,Y)^2]$ not $E[h(X,Y)]^2$; (ii) $aF_X(a)$ should be $a^2F_X(a)$.

Comment: Note that: 1) $h(X,Y) = k \max(X,a) Y$; 2) Since $X$ and $Y$ are independent, so are $\max(X,a)$ and $Y$. Therefore the variance of $h(X,Y)$ is the variance of a product of two independent RVs. Assuming you know how to calculate the second moment of $\max(X,a)$ (I guess you do based on your work), all that is left is a little algebra. Hope this helps.

Comment: @Ellen  : I see you changed the $E[h(X,Y)]^2$ to $E[h(X,Y)^2]$ in your above comment before the 5-minutes expired to change comments.  Of course the $aF_X(a)$ still needs fixing.  The Fnacool comment above is similar to my answer below.  I have deleted my initial comment since it is redundant with my answer below.

Comment: Hi @Michael! Yes I fixed the typo of the squared sign. Then I wanted to fix the $a^2$ but it doesn't allow me to edit again (There's only a delete button.) Anyway thanks for fixing it!

Comment: Thank you @Fnacool! I'm not familiar with the concept of moment. Does "second moment" = variance?

Comment: The second moment of RV $Z$ is $E[Z^2]$, the third moment is $E[Z^3]$, etc.

Answer (score 1):

In general:
$$Var(h(X,Y)) = E[h(X,Y)^2] - E[h(X,Y)]^2$$
so it remains to compute $E[h(X,Y)^2]$.

Here are three ways and you can fill in the details for each way:

#### 1. Basic formula:

$$E[h(X,Y)^2] = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} h(x,y)^2 f_{X,Y}(x,y)dxdy$$
and use $f_{X,Y}(x,y) = f_X(x)f_Y(y)$.

#### 2. Law of total expectation:

$$ E[h(X,Y)^2] = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} E[h(X,Y)^2|X=x]f_X(x)dx$$

#### 3. Observing a product structure:

You can observe $h(X,Y) = g(X)Y$ for some function $g(X)$ and so by independence
$$ E[h(X,Y)] = E[g(X)]E[Y]$$
and so on for $E[h(X,Y)^2]$.